# imagamagick find "fiducial marks" on survey

Tags: pattern-matching, imagemagick

I try to compute the results of a survey.
The process involve scanned surveys and one blank survey.
I want to put fiducial marks in order to align each scan.

My problems are,

- what kind of fiducial marks is better [square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMkOg.png) or [Star](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjH8R.png) or other...
- what pattern detection method should I use. I try `-morphology close 'plus:15x15;cross'`
  then object labelling, but may be I'm on a wrong path...

I use ImageMagick 7.0.10-30 Q16 on Macosx and Ubuntu
my small lines of code:

```
magick blank2_legacy.png  -colorspace RGB -fuzz 20%  -morphology close 'plus:15x15;cross' crp.png
magick crp.png -threshold 50% -define connected-components:verbose=true  -define connected-components:mean-color=true   -connected-components 4 -auto-level -depth 8 objects.png
```

the test image : [blank_legacy image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCBzF.jpg)

Thanks for any help !
Michel
EDIT: distort examples
original:[blank survey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0Stt.jpg)
answers: [distort1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKsKs.jpg)  [distort2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JePzf.jpg)  [Distort3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/999He.jpg)

Comment: Typically a plus mark is used. You can detect them using template matching. In ImageMagick that would be from the compare method. See https://imagemagick.org/script/compare.php and https://imagemagick.org/Usage/compare/ using the -subimage-search option

Comment: I have to say than no subimage matching work in this case, because of scanning distortions. I did try with various options provided, with and without FFT, but it seems (according to developers of solution) it cant work.

Comment: Can you show examples of the distortion you have.

Comment: put some pictures on post

Comment: The two last images are too small to see what is going on.

Comment: I did reedit for largers picts

Comment: Thanks. But so why do you claim fiducial and template matching will not work?

Comment: because I did look for 20 real parts of picture "blank" in distort, one by one, with all methods I can find, in Imagemagick and it never matches. According to experts, It cant because of distortions.

Comment: I do not see any distortions in the example you showed that would cause a mismatch. With template matching in ImageMagick you can use a mask for the template to avoid non-interesting parts. That often helps. If the image is rotated, you can deskew it first. Then do the template matching.  Wrinkles in the image would still permit a match, but the correction would not straighten out the wrinkles. But I do not know of any method that would rectify your image well enough to correct wrinkles.